# Buildship and Eclipse project dependencies

Tags: eclipse, gradle, buildship

We are using eclipse and a buildserver activly. We switched to gradle on the buildsystem first. Therefore we wrote for each eclipse project a gradle file. Using a artefact repository to which it is published, everything worked fine.

Now we are switching our IDEs to buildship. Building a single project works fine. However how can I reference in the build.gradle another eclipse project, without building it first on the buildsystem?

Thanks